# xml parsing iphone, objective C?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, soap, xml-parsing

i want to get data between xml tags? how to navigate? and get values..

im using wsdl2objc from google code:http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/

output soapbody follows:

[image]
read instruction here: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions

my header file: #import "MService.h"

how to get image source and text value????

please help me....

Answer (score 0):

```
 if([bodyPart isKindOfClass:[types_getFavoriteColorResponseType class]]) {
     types_getFavoriteColorResponseType *body = (types_getFavoriteColorResponseType*)bodyPart;
     // Now you can extract the color from the response
     q.text = body.color;
     continue;
}
```

Ок as far as I understand this is a part which extracts text data from your SOAP response.

BTW you need response to be processed via SAX or DOM? First example in given URL refers to DOM usage, whereas the second to SAX.

More than that I can not tell. Guess you have to read manual or find someone, who worked with this.

Comment: i need to proecess response SAX or DOM, get value under src and text value and store in an array to display image and text using navigational screen(with next previous button)

Comment: How urgent is this? I guess I will be able to find some time to read the full manual, but if it is really urgent, I guess you're better off with asking this question to project maintainers. Wish you luck with that.

Comment: hey how to parse and get the src value, no things working...  im using sudzc.com now :(

Answer (score 0):

Use NSXMLParser, NSXMLParserDelegate for xml parsing, you can get the callbacks with proper values:

parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
parser:foundCharacters:
parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: hey how to parse and get the src value, no things working... i'm using sudzc.com now :(

Answer (score 0):

hey i got the result using sudzc.com

```
if ([result isKindOfClass:[MSalesPages class]]) {

    NSLog(@"Response");
    NSMutableArray* pageData = result.PageData;

    for(MSalesPage* page in pageData){
        NSLog(@"Inside for loop %@", page.Id);

        NSMutableArray* images = page.Images;
        NSMutableArray* textData = page.TextData;

        for(MSalesImg* img in images){
            NSLog(@"Image url %@",img.Src);
        }
        for(MSalesText* text in textData){
            NSLog(@"Product Name %@",text.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

carefully check with the above xml, u will get the answer :)